# changing cakephp debug() html

Tags: debugging, cakephp

The CakePHP framework executes the debug function by placing HTML on the view layer. I have implemented a new CSS but the HTML from the debug doesn't work so well with the CSS.

How can I change cake's default HTML to export customer HTML when the debug is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, just look at the source code, it's all hard coded.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.2/lib/Cake/basics.php#L73**
**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.19/cake/basics.php#L126**

So either adapt your CSS, or create your own debug function with custom HTML output.